# Problem with dynamic load graphics in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I make some game, I use I lot of graphics.
I make class that have all graphics for example for menu:

```
public class MenuGFX 
{
    [Embed(source = '../../assets/graphics/menu/background.png')]
    public static const backgroundGFX:Class; 
    [Embed(source='../../assets/graphics/menu/startD.png')] 
    public static const startDGFX:Class; 
    [Embed(source='../../assets/graphics/menu/startO.png')]
    public static const startOGFX:Class; 
    [Embed(source='../../assets/graphics/menu/startU.png')]
    public static const startUGFX:Class; 

}
```

To load graphic from this I use function:

```
public class GraphicsLoader
{
    private static var graphicsDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public static function getGraphic(name:String):Bitmap
    {

        var bitmap:Bitmap = graphicsDictionary[name];
        if (bitmap == null)
        {

            var cls:Object = getDefinitionByName("Graphics::" + name) ;
            bitmap = new (cls);
            graphicsDictionary[name] = bitmap;          
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

But this working only when I add manual creating some graphics: `private var backgroundBitmap:Bitmap = new MenuGFX.backgroundGFX;` to loader class:

```
public class GraphicsLoader
{
    private static var graphicsDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    private var backgroundBitmap:Bitmap = new MenuGFX.backgroundGFX;

    public static function getGraphic(name:String):Bitmap
    {

        var bitmap:Bitmap = graphicsDictionary[name];
        if (bitmap == null)
        {

            var cls:Object = getDefinitionByName("Graphics::" + name) ;
            bitmap = new (cls);
            graphicsDictionary[name] = bitmap;          
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

}
```

I looking for way to avoid making `private var someBitmap:Bitmap = new BitmapName;` . Do you know how can I deal with this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `MenuGFX` will not be compiled into your SWF if the class itself is no where referenced / used within your project source code. It should be enough to call `new MenuGFX` somewhere in your application (may be in your Main class). The compiler has to know that this class will be used somewhere in your application or it will be ignored.